# Issue with Protractor while testing a non angular js website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am currently testing a non Angular js website with protractor. My code is as follows :

```
describe("Login ", function () {

    it("test", co.wrap(function* () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        yield browser.get("URL");
        var elmOK = element(by.css('a[href="#partner"]'))
        yield elmOK.click();
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('login');
    }));

});
```

**Test Scenario :**  My test opens the URL mentioned and selects the link with href=#partner.  A login page which should pop up. But when I run the test and the link is clicked the login page doesn't popp up.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Protractor appears synchronous because it waits for angular to be stable prior to moving to the next action. So if the above was an angular page, it would:

- load the page, then Protractor would wait for angular (wait for the page to be stable)
- tell selenium webdriver to find the element and click on it.

In a **non-angular** page, setting the ignore synchronization set to true in the right direction. What you need to do is to come up with your own sleep between getting the page and clicking the element. After you click on the element, you'll also need to wait for the next window to pop up, change focus to the next window to see if the url contains login.

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.get("URL");

// let the page load
browser.sleep(2000);

element(by.css('a[href="#partner"]')).click().then(() => {
  // may have to add sleep in for the page to load
  browser.sleep(2000);

  // switch to the next window for the popup
  browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then((windowHandles) => {
    let popupLoginHandle = windowHandles[1];
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(popupLoginHandle).then(() => {

      // check to see if the pop up has a url that contains 'login'
      expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('login');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting Hard coded waits is not an good practice.
If you are using jasmine for reporting , you may put the following code inside conf.js:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 600000,
        },
```